# How do I move the hair above the mesh?

Tags: particles, hair

When I am adding hair to my horse model, the hair is going inside the body and not outside as I want. I tried using the particle edit mode but it still doesn't work. That's how it looks like and I want the hair on the upper face.

[image]

Comment: Hello and wecome :). This can have multiple reasons. Could you please upload a few images, and perhaps [share your .blendfile](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ I've edited the post and added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using a separate mesh for "neck hairs" instead of using vertex group of the main horse. It also appears you're using a plane.

My suggestion would be delete the plane, and use vertex groups. You make them while in edit mode, and then assign them in the particle system under "density".  Then you don't have to worry about trying to warp that plane to fit the underlying mesh during animation.

If you *have* to use the plane, then flip the normals, or flip the plane.

Comment: I actually added a duplicate as the scalp but I'll try what you told me :) How do I flip the normals/plane btw? (sorry, started with blender a week ago)

Comment: https://www.katsbits.com/codex/flip-normals/
Started blender about 3 weeks ago.  :D